# Why not run a cable from the north pole to the south pole to access its energy (magnetic or electrical)

Tags: electricity

Would a cable tied to the North Pole around the curve of earth downwards to the South Pole give us access to a HUGE AMOUNT of energy (magnetic or electrical) by linking into it.

Comment: No you will not get any energy. The rotation of earth with the inner core is responsible for magnetic field. No changing mag field is there. Why electrical energy there is no potential driver.

Answer (score 2):

You need a changing magnetic field to induce current (or voltage) in a wire. Since the wire is stationary with the Earth, it is stationary with the Earth's magnetic field.

Comment: Mostly true, but Earth's magnetic field does vary due to solar wind and storms, which can induce some serious voltages in power transmission lines. Not worth building the lines just to collect the "free" power, though.